# Graph: $\big|\frac{2}{zi-2}\big|\leq 4$

Tags: complex-analysis

Graph, plot the set of complex numbers satisfying: $\big|\frac{2}{zi-2}\big|\leq 4$

I am struggling with working on the inequality.

First, $zi = -y + xi$

So,  $\big|\frac{2}{Re(z)-2}\big|\leq 4 \Rightarrow -4 \leq \frac{2}{-y-2} \leq 4 \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2} \leq -y-2 \leq\frac{1}{2}$

Then,  $\big|\frac{2}{Im(z)-2}\big|\leq 4 \Rightarrow -4 \leq \frac{2}{xi-2} \leq4\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2} \leq xi-2 \leq\frac{1}{2}$

Please help me with the inequality and the graph.

Comment: Regarding your approach, it is *not* true in general that $\left| \frac{a}{z}\right|\le b$ implies $\left| \frac{a}{\operatorname{Re}(z)}\right|\le b$ and/or $\left| \frac{a}{\operatorname{Im}(z)}\right|\le b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write it as:

$$\left|\frac{2}{i(z+2i)}\right|\leq 4 \quad\iff\quad |z+2i| \ge\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left|\frac{2}{i}\right| \quad\iff\quad \left|z- (-2i)\right| \ge \frac{1}{2}$$

Then note that the LHS in the latter inequality is the distance between $z$ and the fixed point $-2i\,$.